# How to create a header with chapter names

Tags: macos, ms-word

How can I create a header with chapter names on Microsoft Word 2016 for Mac?
I know that I have to use the button "Field" but I don't know what is the property that I must select.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should try on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) since the question is not about programming.

Comment: Ok, I will try on Super User. Thanks.